# .NET Core Console app on Linux env var NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT - necessary?

Tags: linux, .net-core, .net-6.0

Does environment variable `NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` mean anything when running a console app ?

In asp.net core there is `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` - which (as far as I know) changes the app to use `appsettings.Production.json`.

**Does `NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` exists at all and whats the effect of using it?**

*(I found it in my scripts when I installed 5.0 app almost a year ago, now I cant find any reference of it on Google)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is used by the `HostBuilder` in console apps in .NET 5 & 6 (and maybe as early as 3.x).  Beyond that it's just a common environment variable you can also use to determine the environment in case you wanted to do something like:

```cs
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
{
    builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
}
```

I believe in .NET 5 & 6 `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` are the meaningful environment variables.  If neither are set, it defaults to `Production`.  When run from ASP.NET Core the `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` will prefer `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` if they both exist.

One further side note, I don't believe any values are set by default.  I just checked my local Ubuntu server that has a fresh .NET 6 install on it and those environment variables were not created by the installer.

The following uses `HostBuilder` and the `HostingEnvironment` should reflect the value from `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`.  It still felt unintuitive because I had to add the `prefix: "DOTNET_"` part.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();

        builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "DOTNET_");
        });


        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HostBuilder Environment in ConfigureAppConfiguration: {context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}");
        })
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HostBuilder Environment in UseDefaultServiceProvider: {context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}");
        });

        builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Related:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Do you have any pointers to docs/source code that show `NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in use? I grep'ed through the entire .NET SDK (+ ASP.NET + Runtime) source code and `grep -r -E '[^P]NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'`  has no matches.

Comment: I typo'd my answer, I've updated it now, my apologizes.  DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and -not- NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.  If you search the dotnet repo on GitHub you can find instances of DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT.  I'm updating my answer also with code for a console app that loads from that environment variable (the HostingEnvironment has the correct values then).

Comment: I was fighting with this issue for 4 hours. I did not realize there was a difference (makes absolute sense now that you point it out) between the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT. Thank you so much. Grrrr.